# Pandas DataFrames- value counts from many columns and survey multiple answers

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm struggling with 2 issues:

1. I have an exemplary dataset with cars. 20 respondents was asked about their favorite cars. They could enumerate maximally five cars (columns "Answer 1"- "Answer 5". How can I get number of mentions of each car?
2. For cars mentioned in columns `Answer 1`- `Answer 2` each respondent noted three advantages of each car (for example columns `Adv car 1_1`, `Adv car 1_2`, `Adv car 1_3` are related to first mentioned car, `Adv car 2_1`, `Adv car 2_2`, `Adv car 2_3` are related to second car etc.).
   How can I show how many particular advantages related to each car were mentioned?
   I need informations like this:

   - `Ferrari` - `Engine` 3 times,
   - `Color` - 5 times,
   - `Price` - 3 times etc,
   - `Audi` - `Engine` - 4 times,
   - `Color` - 3 times,
   - `Price` - 2 times etc.

The second issue is related to spss and R variables to cases, but I can't translate it into Python. In this case it is probably related to melting dataframes, but my attempts weren't very effective.

I'll be very thankful for your help. [CSV file is available to download](https://ufile.io/gznkw) or below:

```
No;Answer 1;Answer 2;Answer 3;Answer 4;Answer 5;Adv car 1_1;Adv car 1_2;Adv car 1_3;Adv car 2_1;Adv car 2_2;Adv car 2_3;Adv car 3_1;Adv car 3_2;Adv car 3_3;Adv car 4_1;Adv car 4_2;Adv car 4_3;Adv Car 5_1;Adv car 5_2;Adv car 5_3
1;Ferrari;Volkswagen;Audi;Renault;Toyota;Color;Longevity;Brand;Manufacturer;Color;Longevity;Brand;Manufacturer;Color;Longevity;Brand;Manufacturer;Color;Longevity;Brand
2;Volkswagen;Toyota;Audi;;;Brand;Color;Price;Engine;Color;Longevity;Price;Color;Price;;;;;;
3;Toyota;Renault;;;;Manufacturer;Brand;Engine;Color;Price;Brand;;;;;;;;;
4;Audi;;;;;Engine;Color;Manufacturer;;;;;;;;;;;;
5;Volkswagen;Ferrari;Renault;;;Color;Longevity;Brand;Manufacturer;Color;Longevity;Brand;Manufacturer;Color;;;;;;
6;Renault;Toyota;;;;Brand;Engine;Color;Price;Brand;Manufacturer;;;;;;;;;
7;Audi;Renault;Ferrari;Toyota;;Brand;Color;Price;Engine;Color;Longevity;Price;Color;Price;Longevity;Brand;Manufacturer;;;
8;Toyota;;;;;Engine;Color;Longevity;;;;;;;;;;;;
9;Audi;Ferrari;Volkswagen;;;Engine;Color;Longevity;Price;Color;Price;Longevity;Brand;Manufacturer;;;;;;
10;Renault;Toyota;;;;Color;Longevity;Price;Color;Price;;;;;;;;;;
11;Ferrari;;;;;Longevity;Price;Color;;;;;;;;;;;;
12;Toyota;Volkswagen;Audi;;;Engine;Color;Manufacturer;Engine;Color;Longevity;Price;Color;Price;;;;;;
13;Audi;Volkswagen;Renault;;;Manufacturer;Color;Longevity;Brand;Manufacturer;Color;Longevity;Brand;Manufacturer;;;;;;
14;Volkswagen;;;;;Color;Longevity;Price;;;;;;;;;;;;
15;Toyota;Volkswagen;;;;Brand;Color;Price;Engine;Color;Longevity;;;;;;;;;
16;Ferrari;Renault;Volkswagen;;;Price;Engine;Color;Longevity;Price;Color;Price;Longevity;Brand;;;;;;
17;Audi;Toyota;Renault;;;Color;Longevity;Brand;Manufacturer;Color;Longevity;Brand;Manufacturer;Color;;;;;;
18;Toyota;Audi;Volkswagen;Ferrari;Audi;Color;Longevity;Brand;Manufacturer;Color;Longevity;Brand;Manufacturer;Color;Longevity;Brand;Manufacturer;Color;Longevity;Brand
19;Ferrari;;;;;Engine;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
20;Volkswagen;;;;;Brand;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;data2 = ['Color','Engine','Price','Manufacturer','Brand','Longevity',''];;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  You're likely to get a better answer, faster, if you post a [Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and show what you've tried so far that isn't working.

Comment: I improved the formatting of the question by introducing paragraphs and more highlighting. I also included the downloadable file for easier inspection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_csv('cars.csv',sep=';')

df_car = df.melt(id_vars='No',value_vars=['Answer 1','Answer 2','Answer 3','Answer 4','Answer 5'], value_name='Cars').drop('variable',axis=1)

df_advantages = df.melt(id_vars='No',value_vars=['Adv car 1_1', 'Adv car 1_2', 'Adv car 1_3', 'Adv car 2_1',
       'Adv car 2_2', 'Adv car 2_3', 'Adv car 3_1', 'Adv car 3_2',
       'Adv car 3_3', 'Adv car 4_1', 'Adv car 4_2', 'Adv car 4_3',
       'Adv Car 5_1', 'Adv car 5_2', 'Adv car 5_3'], value_name='Advantages').drop('variable',axis=1)

df_car.merge(df_advantages, on='No').groupby(['Cars','Advantages']).count()
```

Output:

```
                         No
Cars       Advantages      
Audi       Brand         20
           Color         29
           Engine         6
           Longevity     22
           Manufacturer  18
           Price         10
Ferrari    Brand         14
           Color         19
           Engine         4
           Longevity     17
           Manufacturer  10
           Price          9
Renault    Brand         17
           Color         21
           Engine         4
           Longevity     15
           Manufacturer  13
           Price         10
Toyota     Brand         18
           Color         27
           Engine         8
           Longevity     17
           Manufacturer  12
           Price         13
Volkswagen Brand         17
           Color         26
           Engine         6
           Longevity     20
           Manufacturer  13
           Price         12
```

Comment: @jgromadzki  Did this answer help you?

Comment: Dear Scott, this is exactly what I tried to achieve. Thank you very much!